# Brightness is getting change after the reboot/shutdown

Tags: brightness

I have tried changing the brightness.

added `echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to `/etc/rc.local`

But it is temporary change & still getting black screen while login.

How can we set the brightness settings permanently?

Comment: This information is not enough , we need information about your PC and Display driver details.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try editing that line in `/etc/rc.local` to instead be:

`echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

That's what I have in my `rc.local` file, and it works like a charm at every boot no matter what.

Comment: yes it is working...thankyou :) finally got fixed

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Please mark my answer as accepted if it actually helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to startup Applications in the dash.
Add a new startup program "Brightness Level" and add in the command line: xbacklight -set XX
XX being the level you wan at boot. I think it's a 100 scale. I've set mine at 60.
Best,

Comment: I have tried this today. Restarted my laptop to get it checked..it didn't work. Again i am getting the blackscreen while login...I need to press brighntess key for viewing the login screen.  is there anything to do with graphics drivers?